# Are there any disadvantages of using jar files from the internet?

Tags: java

Are there any disadvantages of using jar files from the internet? I'm afraid of downloading jar file from the internet and import to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use MAVEN or a similar library repository, almost every popular library will be managed automatically by the tool and you won't have to bother with dependencies and potential malware.

If you are going to code in JAVA, and are worried about public untrusted .JAR, this is the way to go.

Comment: Note that nobody actually checks that everything uploaded into Maven Central is not malware/spyware or something like this.

Comment: True, but in the mass, if a library contains a malware, it will be detected and removed way faster than if the library is stored on an independent website. It's not 100% proof, but it is still a lot safer.

Answer (score 2):

Its better if it is open source or downloaded from a reliable source.

If it is not downloaded from trusted source then it might be a malware/Trojan horse.

*Also, you could try to decompile JAR file: http://www.google.hr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+decompiler*

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please explain how? or reference

Comment: The JAR itself is safe, executing it is not. It's like any software downloaded from the Internet, some are good, other are bad. Java programs can be just as bad as a malware EXE file. So yeah, trusted source!

Comment: @SeSong , Once you decompile a JAR file you know what it is doing so please undo that down vote. And voted up  if you like.

Comment: @SeSong Lol... I can't tell if there's a typo and "is completely safe" is supposed to be "is not completely safe" Or it's sarcastic? Or it's a technical reference to download vs. execution? Or it's a clever joke because poster's name is same as hacker group anonymous? :P

Comment: You can trust us.   :p

Comment: @Anonymous I downvoted you because your answer was wrong/misleading at the time (and could still use improvement to remove the misleading parts), and because you're begging for upvotes/accepts/rep.

Comment: @Knells , hope you are satisfied with my answer now!

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as the risk of using any other software from the Internet:  there's a chance that it might be malicious, or contain security flaws that attackers can exploit.

Widely-used libraries produced by reputable companies and open-source projects are typically okay.  Niche or amateur software from unknown or inexperienced developers is more risky.  Old software that's no longer maintained is more likely to have known security flaws.

Answer (score 2):

A related question would be, "Is it safe to download programs off the Internet?" Both involve executing some stranger's code.

The answer:

1. Running programs downloaded off the Internet entails some risk.
2. The risk (as does the benefit) depends on many factors!

Same with Java libraries stored in JAR files.

In general, **use common sense**. If you download and use libraries from reputable projects such as apache commons and you verify md5sums, you're probably in fine shape. If you want to use libraries from nefariouswebsite.ru, you may be running a big risk.

Life is full of tradeoffs. This is another classic tradeoff of efficiency vs. security/paranoia. Pick some reasonable balance based on your circumstances.